# Saving data and reading data from Parse.com local datastore on android

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

On android, I'm saving a Username to Parse local datastore

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

ParseObject UserObject = new ParseObject("UsernameClass");

UserObject.put("username", username);    

UserObject.pinInBackground();
```

And to get the saved data I'm using this -

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("UsernameClass");

        query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (ParseObject Userr : ob) {
            Srting user = Userr.get("username");
        }
```

The app is getting crashed and force closed on running. 
**Is the code I'm using wrong somewhere ?**

Comment: did you check that your data (object) upload at server successfully.?

Comment: I'm using this for local datastore, to store data on phone. Why will it get uploaded to server ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453 Can you provide the logs for the issue.

Comment: @BalajiG ... Error:(71, 36) error: incompatible types
required: ParseObject
found:    List<ParseObject>
Error:(78, 42) error: for-each not applicable to expression type
required: array or java.lang.Iterable
found:    ParseObject
Error:(79, 44) error: incompatible types
required: String
found:    Object

Answer (score 1):

to get the saved data add `.fromLocalDatastore();` to query.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("UsernameClass"); 
query.fromLocalDatastore();
```